# How do I make VsCode show operators like ⇒ instead of =>?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I am trying to create an expression sign using "=>" but it is not working. Can you please tell me the name of the extension that can help me with this?

I want a styles vscode expression sign which is like attached image.

Comment: Those are "ligatures". You need a font that supports them ("fira code" is famous for those). Also need to enable them in the settings if they're not enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

use a font that supports font ligatures and enable font ligatures in the settings